# Fastest way to data transfer between computer and NAS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, nas

In office, we share the same network. There is a couple of laptops, one workstation and a Zyxel NAS236. Most of laptops and the workstations runs Ubuntu. I have couple of questions if you don't mind:

1. By default, if I move files from nautilus in ubuntu GUI, will the files will move over router to my laptop, or over internet?
2. What is the fastest way to move files (or maybe syncing a folder) between any of the computers and the NAS?

Do you recommend to setup an ethernet LAN?

Answer (score 0):

1. If all the computers are connected to the router, all the data is transferred on the local LAN
2. The best way to sync folders is likely `rsync` because it optimizes the data transfers

Yes, using Ethernet is likely a lot faster than using Wifi, if the Ethernet ports support Gigabit Ethernet (most modern PC and routers will). Wifi "n" is 600Mbit/s in ideal conditions, when Gigabit Ethernet is routinely 1000Mbits/s(*). But even a 100Mbit/s Ethernet can be faster than a bad Wifi.

(*) Which gives you a practical rate of 100MBytes/second, slightly better than a HDD write rate.